# Pass List of custom object with image from AJax to REST API spring boot

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, rest

Facing issue with Ajax call while passing List of custom object with Image to REST API in sprint boot.
Below is my sample code.

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/test/saveUser" }, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveMission(final UserDTO userDTO,
            @RequestParam(value = "imgFile", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws 
    Exception {
       // service to call save method
    }
```

DTO

```
public class UserDTO{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] thumbNailImage;
    private List<AddressDTO> addressList;
}

public class AddressDTO{

    private String id;
    private String city;
    private String area;
    private String pincode;
}
```

Js code using Ajax

```
let addressList = [];

let addressDTO1 = {"city": "city1","area": "area1","pincode":"pincode1"};
let addressDTO2 = {"city": "city2","area": "area2","pincode":"pincode2"};
addressList.push(addressDTO1);
addressList.push(addressDTO2);
                        
var form = $('#userDetail')[0];

// Create an FormData object 
var data = new FormData(form);
data.append("name", "testUSer");
data.append("addressList", addressList);
data.append("imgFile", File);

$.ajax({
    url: "/test/saveUser",
    data: data,
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
    
    },
    error : function(){
    }
});
```

When I receive ajax request at controller level, I always getting list as an empty.

Comment: For what purpose are you doing `var addressList = {"",""}` prior to sending the request?

Comment: in my actual code it is not there ..here it added by mistake... corrected questions already @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: @Yogesh as I can see you are appending all the things in form data while sending through ajax , So at controller side use MultipartFormDataInput it will capture all your properties and you need to parse them according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are sending all the data using formData you can use MultipartFormDataInput to receive all parameters. Below is the example

```
@Post
@Path("/someurl")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String someUrl(MultipartFormDataInput form) 
{
  try {
    List<InputPart> l = form.getFormDataMap().get("topics");
    String topic1 = l.get(0).getBodyAsString();
    String topic2 = l.get(1).getBodyAsString();
    String topic3 = l.get(2).getBodyAsString();
    // do something with the topics ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "something went wrong";
}
```

you can also refer these link for more examples

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput

https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/